# Visual Studio 2008 Projects and Debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, symbols

I'm not a regular Visual Studio user...

I wanted to make some changes to an existing VS 2008 project that I have.
I copied the project to a new folder.

I seem to be able to update the code in the new location and successfully compile and build.  When I try to use the debugger though I see the error when I hit a breakpoint:

"The source code is different from the original version."

In the output window on startup of the debugger for the project I see that the dll being used for debugging is retrieved from the original folder structure, not the one in the new location.  I also see the wrong path in the Debug->Windows->Modules window.

Seems like it should be easy to specify the correct path somewhere...
I searched over all files in the new project but I don't see a reference to the old path.
And I don't see an option under Project -> Project Properties to set the path.
I deleted all the obj files, did a clean and a rebuild of the project, but that doesn't help.

Where can I change the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple Projects in this solution? Are there references on some projects that are refering to the old path?   You might want to zip up your old soltion and delete it.  Then look for build errors

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try that.  I renamed the original project folder and then tried debugging the new project.  It then picked up the correct paths for the DLL in the new project.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your executable is using the old dll with the executable. Make sure the old dll is not registered (use Regsvr32 /u nameofthedll.dll). I guess your project must build a new dll, so make sure to copy it in the folder of the executable.

If you want to automatize the copy process, you can go in your project properties, build events, post build event and put a line that copy the dll in the $(OutDir) folder. Something like this:
"xcopy /Y /Q /D PathOfNewDll\nameofthedll.dll $(OutDir)"